# Loading lockup on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am programming an application using AJAX and facebook connect.  The location of the application is http://dev.cafexi.com/fbconnect

I'm having what I think is a simple issue

1) When I load the site in any browser except for IE it loads instantaneously - so no issues there

2) When I load in ie 7 or ie 8 it load incredibly slow.  Half the page loads, then it starts doing some javascript calls from facebook and about 15 sec later the page resumes loading.  Any ideas on what may be cassing this?

Do you think that there is a javascript that is causing the issue or do you think there is something with the html?  Any suggestions on what I could investigate further would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You may be modifying the DOM before it is done loading.  IE6 is very sensitive -- if you change a node before it has a chance to finish parsing, I think it corrupts its own rendering engine.

Add a script tag as the last dom node which sets a global variable, then check that variable before doing anything else.  Try this, and then roll a boot-strapper that will run the rest of you JS after DOM:Load.

Comment: Sounds like its an issue in IE 6 - do you think its also and issue in IE7 and IE8?